# amdgpu driver does not create pp_od_clk_voltage

Tags: linux, drivers, gpu

i'm running arch linux and trying to enable amdgpu support for my gpu r9 270x pitcairn architecture. i'm trying to enable core clock control through pp_od_clk_voltage. someone pointed out to me that apparently amdgpu driver does not create the file in the system if this condition is not met in amdgpu_pm.c

```
if ((is_support_sw_smu(adev) && adev->smu.od_enabled) ||
        (!is_support_sw_smu(adev) && hwmgr->od_enabled)) {
        ret = device_create_file(adev->dev,
                &dev_attr_pp_od_clk_voltage);
        if (ret) {
            DRM_ERROR("failed to create device file "
                    "pp_od_clk_voltage\n");
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

is it possible for me to fix this as i'm trying to find a way to control gpu core clock.

Comment: Why would you want to "correct it"? That `if` statement checks for the availability of the feature. If it's not supported by your GPU, enabling it is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: Also, have you tried adding `amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff` to your kernel boot parameters? That would enable all features, including this one *if supported*.

Comment: Relevant: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106188

Comment: yes i already enabled it in grub config. this is not a linux problem but a hardware failure on my side. the pc crash randomly and it runs perfectly fine if i underclock the gpu core clock slightly lower. its not an overheating problem either. i've installed tlp but it didn't help. so i'm looking for a feature to adjust gpu core clock like in windows with catalyst proprietary driver and ran into a dead end.

Comment: i dont think its a bug as the file pp_od_clk_voltage is missing from the system leading me to think the feature is not supported or disabled by default.

Comment: Yes it's not a bug, that's what I was saying. The driver doesn't create the file because the feature is not supported by your GPU. There really isn't much you can do, except of course manually editing the driver code and recompile it installing your own version in place of the existing one. I would 100% not advise it though.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i ask the question in the first place because i don't know if there is a possibility for me to do something about my problem. i have been asking around looking for answer for months and no one would straight up tell me that its not possible.